# JS Proxy & destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, proxy, assign, destructuring

As what i know js Proxies make possible to overload classic object getter with a function call.

So that we can do things like that :

```
const value = myProxy.value;
```

All that calling in fact the value getter function inside Proxy.

My question is ... is there a way to use the JS destructuring syntax with JS Proxies ?

So that we could do things like that :

```
const { value } = myProxy;
```

Based on my tests, the second way is not working.

Comment: Please show us the code of the "tests" that you did.

Comment: It looks like the problem come from the lib i use: express-session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working with a necessary implemented getter.

```js
const
    myProxy = new Proxy({}, {
        get: function(obj, prop) {
            return 42;
        }
    }),
    { value } = myProxy;

console.log(myProxy.value);
console.log(value);
```